# compiler does not allow me to edit the passed string

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, string-literals

I looked around and I could not find a solution of my problems in other question. For some reason, then I get segmentation fault when I run my program and it seems to be because i am changing the give string. I tried passing a pointer to a char pointer and edit that, but to no avail.

### what I get:

before: juanpablo
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

### My code:

```
void rm_char(char* word, int pos){

   printf("before: %s\n", word);

   int len = strlen(word);

   int i;

   i = pos;

   while(word[i+1] != '\0'){

     word[i] = word[i+1];

     i++;
   } 

   word[i] = '\0';

   printf("after: %s\n", word);
} 


int main(void){

   rm_char("juanpablo", 2);

}
```

Comment: The only duty of the compiler - is to compile the code. If it is doing it, the rest is about the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

To escape the error you could call the function like

```
char s[] = "juanpablo";   

rm_char( s, 2 );
```

Take into account that it is better to use type `size_t` instead of the type `int` for the second parameter and the variable `len` declared like

```
int len = strlen(word);
```

is not used in the function.

The function should be declared like

```
char * rm_char(char* word, size_t pos);
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * rm_char(char *word, size_t pos)
{
    size_t n = strlen( word );

    if ( pos < n )
    {
        //memmove( word + pos, word + pos + 1, n - pos );
        do 
        {
            word[pos] = word[pos+1];
        } while ( word[pos++] );
    }

    return word;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char word[] = "juanpablo";

    puts( word );
    puts( rm_char( word, 2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
juanpablo
junpablo
```

Comment: So, let me see if i understand, if a make  string using malloc() and strcpy(), it is impossible to edit it because it is a string literal. Or it is is because I passed a string in double quotes, "string literal" that i'm unable to edit it?

Comment: @Telegonicaxx You passed to the function a pointer to the first character of a string literal and using this pointer you are trying to change the string literal within the function.

Comment: thanks you @Vlad from Moscow! I was really scratching my head with this one.